# Android OrientationEventListener SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL Necessity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mediaplayer, android-sensors, android-orientation

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener#OrientationEventListener(android.content.Context,%20int)), which says:

> Use the default value of SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL for simple screen orientation change detection.

Does it mean that if I don't include the sensor rate in the constructor, it will still apply the `SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL`?

In other words, are this two the same:

```
OrientationEventListener(context)

OrientationEventListener(context, Sensor.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)
```

**PS: I use for simple screen orientation change detection.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the official source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/OrientationEventListener.java), the former constructor is defined as follows,

```
/**
 * Creates a new OrientationEventListener.
 * 
 * @param context for the OrientationEventListener.
 */
public OrientationEventListener(Context context) {
    this(context, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
```

So, it's completely equivalent to the latter. You can use whichever you like.